# A site for life-outside-work issues dedicated to programmers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is there a SO related site dedicated to issues faced by programmers for life outside work?e.g:
Health/Relationships? if not, maybe create one..
Most of the popular forums dealing with these kind of issues are open to all..and it can be difficult to relate sometimes.
The relationship problems faced by a person working in adult industry is different than that of a programmer.
The health problems of an athlete is different from that of a programmer. etc. etc etc.

Comment: yes, there's a support group for that. it's called a "bar". I hear they serve drinks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are athletic programmers who work in "adult" industries... The truth is, "life" questions from programmers aren't usually all that different from those of other professions.

Yes, the challenges you face in your daily non-work life are considerably different from those of your friend the investment-banking cyclist. Then again, they're probably also considerably different from *mine*. Many different factors influence our lives, and grouping questions by profession isn't necessarily any more effective than grouping them by age, race, location, or favorite food.

Not that there's anything inherently wrong in carving out a niche... But if you're going to do so [on Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/a-site-for-life-outside-work-issues-dedicated-to-programmers/1243#1243), there better be enough people firmly dedicated to that niche to sustain it. Trying to get around that by grouping a bunch of mostly-unrelated niche topics together (programmer-HEALTH, programmer-RELATIONSHIPS, programmer-COMPETITIVE ROSE GROWING) just ends up creating a site about anything and nothing at all... and that won't fly. [We sorta tried that already...](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352?phase=definition)

Stack Exchange isn't a social network or a support group. It's about questions, and their answers. If you can ask a health question in a way that makes it sufficiently unique to the software development profession, [it *might* find a home on this site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38299/do-computer-glasses-work)... Otherwise, you'd be better off asking it on a dedicated health site.

Comment: Love your sarcasm

Comment: 'athletic programmers who work in "adult" industries..' But you wouldn't know the guy's linkedin profile....would you? Because I would sure take a gander

Comment: I do... But I'm not sure he really wants that sort of attention. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Victor, have you checked out [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

It's a proposal system for creating new StackExchange sites. It's how Programmers was created.  If you're interested in creating new SE sites that don't match any current sites, in helping to define new sites, or discuss the problems with existing sites ([discuss.area51.stackexchange.com](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/)), that's the place to be.